# How to make titles bold based on date in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a WordPress site with static front page and it displays featured and recent posts....I am not using any widgets to achieve this, just using a custom home page template.

My requirement is to make the post titles bold based on date i.e., for instance I want the posts published today to be displayed in bold.....thanks in advance

Comment: Try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I made this fast javascript for you as a hint,

```
$('.date').each(function(){
  if($(this).text() == "03.03.03"){
    $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
  }
});
```

also here is a demo for it [CodePen DEMO](http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/XJqqxz)

find the class or id you need to make it bold; Also you did not mention the date format you got in order for me to make the script for you. Hope this helps.

Cheers